# how to handle string exception in python

Tags: python

program to find the division of two numbers with exception handling. Exceptions could if one or both of my two variables are string or denominator is zero. Raise exceptions accordingly and catch it with printing different message for different exception.

```
def divide(a, b): 
    try:
        if b.isalpha():
            raise ValueError('dividing by string not possible')
        c= a/b 
        print('Result:', c)
    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        print("dividing by zero not possible ")
divide(3,abc)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That last line of code should be ```divide(3,'abc')```, not ```divide(3,abc)```.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to divide with strings, you get a `TypeError`. Python endorses an "ask forgiveness, not permission" approach, so instead of checking whether your expression will parse correctly, you should just wait to catch a `TypeError` if it happens (as a bonus, this also accommodates for other non-numeric datatypes that don't work with division).

Also, and this might be what you don't know, you can chain `except` clauses to each other to capture different kinds of exceptions from the same `try` block, and deal with them differently.

Example:

```
def divide(a, b): 
    try:
        c= a/b 
        print('Result:', c)
    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        print("dividing by zero not possible ")
    except TypeError:
        print("a and b must both be integers")
        # you could do additional checks in here if you wanted to determine which
        #   variable was the one causing the problem, e.g. `if type(a) != int:`
```